# Assigning pointer in an exterior function

Tags: function, pointers, segmentation-fault

My problem is the following:
in the main I have somewhere

```
Shape* ext = NULL;
FieldProbPhys2D* Fprob = NULL;
(...)
createCircleExt(ext, Fprob);
```

and I want to assign the shape pointer outside the main (I admit it is just a question of not having an textually overloaded main).
I have a Utility.h and its corresponding Utility.cpp (where createCircleExt is defined):

```
void createCircleExt(Shape* f, FieldProbPhys2D* field) {
(...)
f = new Circle(r, r, r);
(...)
field = new FieldProbPhys2D(Nx, Ny, 2*r, 2*r, Vg);
```

}

when I run this I get a segmentation fault and valgrind tells me:  Access not within mapped region at address 0x0

Does that mean that the assignement is only local ? If that is the case, how can I fix it ?

Thanks a lot!

Simon

Answer (score 0):

f and field are a pointer. They are copied in the frame of `createCircleExt()`.
There, the local copies will be overrwritten. If you leave `createCircleExt()`, the old values are still valid.

Probably , you want to use pointers to pointers, or references.